# Combine outputs and test results from many regression models in one csv file

Tags: r

I have done multiple regression in a loop for various combination of the regressors (these add up 25 models). The summary outputs from each of these models have been saved in a list of lists. Each component of the list is the summary output from one regression – which is a list by itself.

For each of these regression models, I have performed the Durbin Watson test, the Breusch Godfrey test, the Breusch Pagan test and the Shapiro Wilk test. The summary of the fit and the output from these tests have been saved in their individual csv files with each of these csv files containing the full results for the test for all of the 25 models one after the other.

I actually would prefer to store the summary output and the results from all of the tests for each of these models together one after the other in the same file like so :-

Model summary output – for model 1

Durbin-Watson test – for model 1

Shapiro-Wilk normality test – for model 1

etc.

Model summary output – for model 2

Durbin-Watson test – for model 2

Shapiro-Wilk normality test – for model 2

etc.

These commans generate the relevant files containing the results for the relevant test for all the 25 models

```
filename1 <- "mytestfileFinal.csv"
for (i in 1:length(modelfits1)) {
    testoutput <- summary(modelfits1[[(i)]])
    capture.output(testoutput, file = filename1, append = TRUE)
}
```

Output like so :-

> Time series regression with "zoo" data: Start = 2016-10-03, End =
>   2017-03-31
>
> Call: dynlm(formula = as.formula(modelformula1))
>
> Residuals:
>       Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
>   -5308.9 -1110.4   -29.1  1130.9  6036.2
>
> Coefficients:
>                                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     (Intercept)                           -4.51086  141.70680
>   -0.032   0.9746     as.zoo(dtempxts_1610_1703)          -168.43261   41.65874  -4.043 7.89e-05 *** L(as.zoo(dusagexts_1610_1703), 1:1)   -0.12407    0.07438  -1.668   0.0971 .   L(as.zoo(dtempxts_1610_1703), 1:1)    26.23201   44.00455   0.596   0.5519     as.zoo(cointresL1)
>
>   -0.21260    0.05154  -4.125 5.73e-05** 
>   --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘**’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 1901 on 175 degrees of freedom Multiple
>   R-squared:  0.1812,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.1625  F-statistic:  9.68 on
>   4 and 175 DF,  p-value: 4.275e-07
>
> Time series regression with "zoo" data: Start = 2016-10-04, End =
>   2017-03-31
>
> Call: dynlm(formula = as.formula(modelformula1))
>
> Residuals:
>       Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
>   -5358.0 -1130.5   -48.5  1138.8  6016.9
>
> Coefficients:
>                                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     (Intercept)                           -2.05255  142.86944
>   -0.014 0.988554     as.zoo(dtempxts_1610_1703)          -163.37609   44.66815  -3.658 0.000338 *** L(as.zoo(dusagexts_1610_1703), 1:1)   -0.12522    0.07515  -1.666 0.097504 .   L(as.zoo(dtempxts_1610_1703), 1:2)1   30.06316   46.02972   0.653 0.514543
>
>   L(as.zoo(dtempxts_1610_1703), 1:2)2   12.47362   45.30022   0.275
>   0.783373     as.zoo(cointresL1)                    -0.21473    0.05245  -4.094  6.5e-05** 
>   --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘**’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 1911 on 173 degrees of freedom Multiple
>   R-squared:  0.1818,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.1581  F-statistic: 7.687 on
>   5 and 173 DF,  p-value: 1.501e-06

```
filename1 <- "mytestfile_st.csv"
for (i in 1:length(modelfits1)) {
    stoutput <- shapiro.test(modelfits_res[[i]]$residuals)
    capture.output(stoutput, file = filename1, append = TRUE)
}
```

> Output like so :- Shapiro-Wilk normality test
>
> data:  modelfits_res[[i]]$residuals W = 0.99192, p-value = 0.4316
>
> Shapiro-Wilk normality test
>
> data:  modelfits_res[[i]]$residuals W = 0.98642, p-value = 0.07991

```
filename1 <- "mytestfile_dwt.csv"
for (i in 1:length(modelfits1)) {
    dwtoutput <- dwtest(modelfits1[[i]])
    capture.output(dwtoutput, file = filename1, append = TRUE)
}
```

> Output like so :- Durbin-Watson test
>
> data:  modelfits1[[i]] DW = 2.094, p-value = 0.7247 alternative
>   hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0
>
> Durbin-Watson test
>
> data:  modelfits1[[i]] DW = 2.0239, p-value = 0.5517 alternative
>   hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0

I tried the code below (for 1 model only to test) to achieve what I was trying to do but this doesn’t work.

```
filename1 <- "mytestfile_alltest.csv"
for (i in 1: 1)) {
    stoutput <- shapiro.test(modelfits_res[[i]]$residuals)
    dwtoutput <- dwtest(modelfits1[[i]])
    fulloutput <- cat(stoutput, dwtoutput, sep = "\n")
    capture.output(fulloutput, file = filename1, append = TRUE)
}
```

Actual output from my code that doesn't work :-

> The output from the above code is like so :-
>
> [1] "c(W = 0.986424495866567)\nc(DW = 2.09395526077259)"
>   "0.0799081371360976\nDurbin-Watson test"
>   [3] "Shapiro-Wilk normality test\ntrue autocorrelation is greater than
>   0" "modelfits_res[[i]]$residuals\n0.724719582360738"
>   [5] "c(W = 0.986424495866567)\nmodelfits1[[i]]"

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to save the printed results, as they're not rectangular. I'd suggest using [broom](https://broom.tidyverse.org/), then writing CSVs.

Comment: @alistaire <- Thanks fo rpointing me to the broom package. That is excellent and it would do all I need to do.  I need to store this information for audit trail purposes. With the broom package, the relevant information can even be stored on our database system. Great stuff!